# How can I register System.Logger for JUnit

Tags: java, logging

I'm working on a small library where I don't want dependencies on any particular logger. I implement System.Logger and that should be fine from the library point of view.

Now, for my JUnit tests I want to register that logger with SLF4J with Logback rather than use JUL. How can I do that?

I tried many searches to find a tutorial for this with no luck.

Comment: http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html

Comment: @BoristheSpider what about it? My library does not want any dependencies.

Comment: If you want to use SLF4J with Logback for your tests, then you already have extra dependencies - for your tests - then why is adding an extra dependency for your tests a problem?

Comment: You mention both System.Logger and JUL, which are **not** the same thing. Which are you actually using?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I thought that System.Logger defaulted to JUL when no other logger finders were on the classpath? But totally- they’re not the same thing.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel For my Unit tests I use SLF4J but my POM marks all these dependencies as TEST.  So for my library itself though, it has no dependencies.  Currently I use a Log delegate where I check which logger is available. I thought maybe with Java9 I could replace my implementation with the built-in way now.   You can see what I mean on my github project search for "persism"

Comment: When you use System.Logger it defaults to JUL - that's why I mentioned it.

Comment: Yes. So add the JUL bridge _for your tests_ and you’re done. I’m not sure what the problem is or what the purpose of this discussion is.